# filter matrix based on another table in power bi

Tags: powerbi, dax, dashboard, powerbi-desktop

I am trying to display in a matrix only rows that are assigned by different tables. Below are examples of my tables.

[image: measures fact table]

[image: measures specialty dim]

[image: category dim]

I want an output similar to the image below [image: mock up] but I need a graph for each measure. At this time I think that I need to create an individual graph for each measure and update them independently (that may be a separate issue). I want to only display the measures that are assigned to the individual that I select.

The fact table has thousands of rows with hundreds of people. I am looking to produce a dashboard that displays the rates for one person's assigned measures based on the measures assigned to them from their specialties. I've done many searches and haven't found a similar enough question and tried using the RELATEDTABLE function without success.

Here are my relationships I've created:

[image: relationships]

The only way I was able to get the display to work properly was to create an additional table that lists the measures as rows, each specialty is a column and is binary (see below).

[image: binary table]

I currently have to select the specialty within this table (binary specialty) as a filter then filter for the value "1" to get the display correct, showing only assigned measures. This is not effective; I am looking to be able to select the person and have the measures assigned to them automatically display. I'm relatively new to DAX and I feel like there must be a way.

Comment: I'm not quite following what it is that you want to see. Can you mock up what you want your report to look like? Also, please post an image of your table relationships.

Comment: what is the rationale for setting all relations in the data model as bidirectional?

Comment: I need to be able to select a person's name from the Roster and have the measures fact display only their values. I may be wrong in the way that the relationships are set up, but that's my rationale.